# How do I get the integral of $\frac{1}{(x^2 - x -2)}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm working with this problem $$ \int \frac{1}{x^2 - x - 2}$$

I'm thinking I break up the bottom so that it looks like this $$\int \frac{1}{(x-2)(x+1)} $$

Then I do $$x^2 - x -2 =  \frac{A}{x-2} + \frac{B}{x+1} $$

Multiple both sides by the common denominator and come out with $$ A(x+1) + B(x-2) = x^2 - x - 2 $$

Which equals $$Ax + A + Bx - 2B = x^2 - x - 2$$

Or $$ (A+B)x + (A-2B) = x^2 - x - 2$$

After that I tried to get values for my A and B but it doesn't seem right since I don't have anything for the $x^2$

Did I mess up somewhere?

Comment: you need to equate numerators, instead you equate a denominator of one fraction (LHS) to a numerator of the other one (RHS)

Comment: (+1) for showing work and following up with comments. This question should be in the FAQ about "how to ask a (homework) question"!

Comment: The Maple command $$Student[Calculus1]:-IntTutor(1/(x^2-x-2), x) $$ produces that step by step with explanations. See [the link](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=examples/Calculus1SingleStepping) and [the output](http://rapidshare.com/share/9ED6DED0DBAA3F0BE740D8BA0E5B7AA2).

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 Thank you for the compliment. I try to put in some effort before I ask the question because I know that those who respond with an answer are giving me their time to help me :)

Comment: @user64494 Thank you for the link, that is a pretty neat website. I'll have to tinker with it tonight when I have some free time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is in the step where you write:

$$x^2 - x -2 =  \frac{A}{x-2} + \frac{B}{x+1}$$

What you have, actually, is $$\dfrac 1{x^2 - x - 2} = \dfrac A{x-2} + \frac B{x+1}$$

So $A(x+1) + B(x - 2) = 1$.

If $x = -1$, $$A(-1 + 1) + B(-1 - 2) = 1 \iff -3B = 1 \iff B = -\frac 13$$

If $x = 2$, $$A(2 + 1) + B(2 - 2) = 1 \iff 3A = 1 \iff A = \frac 13$$

$$\int \dfrac {dx}{x^2 - x - 2} = \int \left(\dfrac A{x-2} + \frac B{x+1}\right)\,dx = \int \left(\frac 1{3(x-2)} - \frac{1}{3(x + 1)}\right)\,dx$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: If $x=2$, then $3A=1$ implies $A=\frac 1 3$.

Comment: I'm getting A = $\frac{1}{3}$ and B = $-\frac{1}{3}$ Other than that, I'll try and take it from here and report back.

Comment: Yes, those are the correct values for $A, B$. We pick $x = -1, x = 2$ to "zero out" one of the variables, and solve for the other. "Cover up method," so to speak.

Comment: Am I able to just do $ ln|3x -2| + ln|3x+1| + c$ or do I need to worry about a 0 on the bottom?

Comment: The original answer can be seen [here](http://rapidshare.com/share/9D70C6365F86B411E8B84BCD7917D6DD).

Comment: @user64494 We all make typos...mine led to an initial calculation error. Thankfully, I caught it. The process is correct. Lighten up! ;-) ... At least I don't post answers spit out by software... :-)

Comment: ConfusingCalc, you can do $$\dfrac 13 \ln|3x -6| + \frac 13\ln|3x + 3| + C$$ We have $u = 3x - 6, u' = 3x + 3 \implies du = du' = 3 dx \iff dx = \frac 13 du.$ The x values used to shorten the computation of the variables $A, B$ were just chosen arbitrarily to solve for their values.

Comment: To add to the previous comment... "We *could* just take any two values of x, and that would result is a system of two equations with unknowns A and B. However, with clever choice of x-values, we can significantly shorten the process". Or something like that :)

Comment: Your explanation is much better than mine, @TheChaz2.0 ! :-)

Comment: Well your Latex is much better than mine! I just wanted to give the OP a more thorough explanation since they have been real good about commenting and asking for clarification. Most do not get such treatment (mwahahaha!)

Answer (score 2):

You need to do $$\frac 1{x^2-x-2}=\frac A{x-2}+\frac B{x+1}$$

Clear fractions (multiply both sides by $x^2-x-2$) to obtain $$1=A(x+1)+B(x-2)$$

You should be able to do it from there. Easy way - set $x=2$, $x=-1$

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'm unsure of whether you or amWhy was first.

Answer (score 1):

In your partial fraction,

$\dfrac{1}{(x-2)(x+1)} = \dfrac{A}{x-2} + \dfrac{B}{x+1}$

So,

$\dfrac{1}{(x-2)(x+1)} = \dfrac{A(x+1) + B(x-2)}{(x-2)(x+1)}$

and hence,

$1 = (A+B)x + (A-2B)$

I think you can take it from here.

Comment: Thank you crypton480, I appreciate it!